# What does axis (0, 1) means in function np.std()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

For an array:

```
a= np.array([[[2, 3, 2, 1]],

       [[1, 2, 0, 2]]])
```

why there are different results for this:

```
np.std(a)
output: 0.8569568250501305
```

and this:

```
np.std(a, (0,1))
output: array([0.5, 0.5, 1. , 0.5])
```

Doesn't (0,1) mean all axis? Why it happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `(0, 1)` doesn't mean all axes here, because your `array` is `3D`.

```
>>> a= np.array([[[2, 3, 2, 1]],

       [[1, 2, 0, 2]]])

>>> a.shape
(2, 1, 4)

>>> a.ndim
3
```

Now, let's see how the axis parameters work:

```
# Let's take a 2D array:

>>> two_d = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
>>> two_d
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

# if we were to use, np.mean with axis=0, you can visualize this by thinking, 
# for each index of axis other than axis=0, it gets all the values along axis=0,
# and computes mean, so:

           all vals along 0 , first index of other axis
>>> two_d[       :          ,             0            ]
array([0, 4, 8])
>>> two_d[:, 0].mean()
4.0
           all vals along 0 ,  2nd index of other axis
>>> two_d[       :          ,            1             ].mean()
5.0
# 3rd index
>>> two_d[:, 2].mean()
6.0
# 4th index
>>> two_d[:, 3].mean()
7.0

# So when you do:
>>> np.mean(two_d, axis=0) # You end up with
array([4., 5., 6., 7.])
```

Now in your case, you are getting `std` on `axis=(0,1)`, so you will iterate over indices of `axis=2` and get all the values for that index along `axis 0 and axis 1`, as there are 4 values across axis 2 (because shape == `(2, 1, 4)`), there will be 4 values:

```
>>> a[:, :, 0]
 
array([[2],
       [1]])

>>> a[:, :, 1]
 
array([[3],
       [2]])

>>> a[:, :, 2]  
array([[2],
       [0]])

>>> a[:, :, 3]  
array([[1],
       [2]])
>>> a[:, :, 0].std()
0.5
>>> a[:, :, 1].std()
0.5
>>> a[:, :, 2].std()
1.0
>>> a[:, :, 3].std()
0.5

# So when you do 
>>> np.std(a, axis=(0,1))
array([0.5, 0.5, 1. , 0.5])
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [NumPy documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.std.html), here is what the `axis` parameter does:

> If this is a tuple of ints, a standard deviation is performed over multiple axes, instead of a single axis or all the axes as before.

Comment: i was asking about meaning of axis = (0,1) in function np.std

Comment: Reredf, that's the meaning of the axis parameter in `np.std`.  What don't you understand?

Comment: @PriyanshulGovil have you tried calculating `np.std` along `axis=1` on the resultant array of `np.std(a, axis=0)`?

Comment: @SayandipDutta Oh right, I messed up with the explanation. Although, this is more of a [math](https://www.math.stackexchange.com) question as all it is based on is calculation of standard deviation. Nevertheless, thanks for the info. I'll remove the incorrect part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `a` has shape `2,1,4`.

The axis argument tells you which axis will be reduced.

So `np.std(a,axis=(0,1))` reduces the shape from `2,1,4` to `4`.

Comment: reduces the shape of initial array? and how does it look so?